# Python SQLite3 issue searching table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Python function that is supposed to check if a value is present in my SQLite table. I have a table named `Users` and it stores the value `userid` which is a random string of integers and letters. For example, a `userid` would look like this `f75fsf3dbg9g`. In `def chk():` the user inputs their `uid` then the `uid_chk():` function is called to check if the `uid` value equals one of the `userid` being stored in the table.

My issue is in the `cur.execute(query,tagValue)` line in the `uid_chk()` function. It throws the **Error**: *sqlite3.programmingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1*
Nothing is being returned from the function `uid_chk()` just prints out `None`

For reference when the table `Users` is printed out it looks like this: `[('hk12lkj14vh',),('bn465i32',),('d8j4k0fl',),('k4i9b3k0s2',),('rk2nk50sp26',),('rk3ji9al23',),]`

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sqlite3 as sql
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

def chk():
    print("Scan tag")
    try:
        uid_tag = reader.read()
        #If the user has inputed value (uid)
        if uid_tag :
            #Var for inputed userid 
            tagValue = uid_tag[1]
            print(tagValue)
            uid_chk(tagValue)
            return tagValue
            GPIO.cleanup()
    except ValueError:
        print('Something went wrong')
       
    

def uid_chk(tagValue):
    Database = sql.connect('test.db')
    # cursor
    cur = Database.cursor()
    # Check if the tagValue maches a value in the userid column of sqlite DB
    query = 'SELECT userid FROM Users WHERE userid = ?'
    cur.execute(query, tagValue)
    row_returned = cur.fetchone()
    print(row_returned)
    if row_returned == tagValue:
        print('User Verified')
    else:
        print('Something is Wrong')
        Database.close()

chk()
```

Comment: The string `tagValue` is interpreted as sequence of characters here, use `cur.execute(query, (tagValue,))` instead.

Comment: In addition to that, you have a serious problem in `chk()` - `tagValue` is not always initialized before it is used.

Comment: @zvone Which line in `chk()` do you believe is erroneous? Would it be better to change the `finally ` to an `except` and consolidate `return` to the `try:`

Comment: @tibaH_lluN You have changed the code in the meantime ;) Previously, the reference to `tagValue` in `finally` block was used, but `tagValue` was initialized only in some cases, not always.

Comment: @zvone So after adding the changes to my code I am still having issues. The problem is the function `uid_chk()` is not returning anything, it just prints out `None`

Comment: @tibaH_lluN Well, if you want `uid_chk()` to return something, you should add a `return something` to the function. Currently it does not return anything.

Comment: @zvone Would adding `return cur.fetchone()` possibly work?